# Reverse this jQuery slideshow plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help to reverse this plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var currentDiv = 0;
$('#wof #arrowRight').click(function() {
    $('.group' + (currentDiv + 1)).fadeOut(250);
    currentDiv = (currentDiv + 1) % 5;
    $('.group' + (currentDiv + 1)).delay(250).fadeIn(250);
}); 
});
```

This is the right arrow, i need one with left arrow so you go back one number.
I tried this, but it kinda broke the plugin.

```
$('#wof #arrowLeft').click(function() {
    $('.group' + (currentDiv + 1)).fadeOut(250);
    currentDiv = (currentDiv + 1) % 5;
    $('.group' + (currentDiv - 1)).delay(250).fadeIn(250);
}); 
});
```

So how do i do this the smartest way?

Comment: The smartest way would be to set up a jsFiddle so we can see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#wof #arrowLeft').click(function() {
    $('.group' + (currentDiv + 1)).fadeOut(250);
    currentDiv = currentDiv - 1;
    if (currentDiv < 0)
        currentDiv = 4;
    $('.group' + (currentDiv + 1)).delay(250).fadeIn(250);
});
```

You need to decrease `currentDiv`, not increase it.